# git push via ssh and who knows the private key?

Tags: git, ssh, git-push, gitbucket

This is a conceptional question.

When setting up a ssh connection to gitbucket/github, I am creating a private ssh key which is then used for creating the public ssh key.

Then I add the public key to gitbucket.

Hence as my computer hold the private key, it can decrypt the encrypted messages coming from gitbucket.

So I understand for example how git clone works.

But gitbucket has no own private key, and I did not add a public key to my computer which was generated by that (non existing) private key. So how should git push work via ssh???

Comment: Gitbucket uses the public key to encrypt messages, and you use your private key to decrypt them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But [gitbucket](https://github.com/takezoe/gitbucket) has no own private key

It doesn't need a private key, only the public one in order to *authenticate* you.

Once gitbucket knows who is contacting for a clone or a push, it will allow the operation.
For the push, it works if you are the owner of the repo to which you are pushing to.

For the [authentication part (`ssh/PublicKeyAuthenticator.scala`)](https://github.com/takezoe/gitbucket/blob/334753b1adf7e14e9c6ce865e1dfbd6b64880763/src/main/scala/ssh/PublicKeyAuthenticator.scala#L14-L16) in gitbucket, see for instance:

- [`src/main/scala/model/SshKey.scala`](https://github.com/takezoe/gitbucket/blob/2ebf2b99bd1879c51573decdfa1934f49678dac6/src/main/scala/model/SshKey.scala#L9) for retrieving the username
- [`src/main/scala/service/SshKeyService.scala`](https://github.com/takezoe/gitbucket/blob/2ebf2b99bd1879c51573decdfa1934f49678dac6/src/main/scala/service/SshKeyService.scala#L10) for storing the username along with the public key.

The server side (gitbucket) needs only the public key because of the way [public key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) works.

Comment: How does it authenticate me with the public key? Is it sending like a encrypted string which then can only be decrypted by the computer which holds the private key and then sends back the decrypted string?